# PHP join 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays

```
$array1 = array(
    ['2013-05-01']=>'test',
    ['2013-05-02']=>'testing',
    ['2013-05-03']=>'working',
    ['2013-05-04']=>'future test');

$array2 = array(
    ['2013-05-01']=>'1',
    ['2013-05-02']=>'done',
    ['2013-05-03']=>'code',
    ['2013-05-05']=>'release');
```

I want to join these array, so that output is

```
$result = array(
        ['2013-05-01']=>'test 1', 
        ['2013-05-02']=>'testing 2',
        ['2013-05-03']=>'working code',
        ['2013-05-04']=>'future test',
        ['2013-05-05']=>'release')
```

I tried $result = $array1 + array2; array_merge() , array_combine() none gave the correct result.

Can you help me please.

Comment: You need to write your own code to do this. There is no built in functions.

Comment: you mean using foreach loop?

Comment: It keeps surprising me that people expect PHP to have a builtin function for every single scenario that a starting programmer should be able to solve without effort.

Comment: `function array_join($arr1, $arr2) {return array(['2013-05-01']=>'test 1', ['2013-05-02']=>'testing 2',['2013-05-03']=>'working code');}` - just messing ;)

Comment: Your given code doesn't even compile properly.

Comment: Niels, Humans are lazy :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foreach($array2 AS $key => $value)
{
    $array1[$key] = isset($array1[$key]) ? $array1[$key] . " " . $value : $value;
}
```

Comment: Error handling for what? The case that $array1 doesn't contain the keys of $array2 is taken care of.

Comment: I _suggest_ to use `isset()` instead of `empty()`.

Comment: Good suggestion. If $array1 would contain a '0' as value, it would be deleted this way.

Comment: @zerkms There are a lot of `empty()` calls? `:)))` `empty($array1[$key])` suggested to be `isset($array1[$key])`.

Comment: @CORRUPT: I mean "for what reason". Now after `'0'` example I see

Comment: This has the potentially unintended side effect of modifying `$array1`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a one-line solution for the issue:

```
$array1 = array(
    '2013-05-01'=>'test',
    '2013-05-02'=>'testing',
    '2013-05-03'=>'working',
    '2013-05-04'=>'future test');

$array2 = array(
    '2013-05-01'=>'1',
    '2013-05-02'=>'done',
    '2013-05-03'=>'code',
    '2013-05-05'=>'release');


$r = array_map(function($i) {
    return !is_array($i) ? $i : implode(' ', $i);
}, array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2));

var_dump($r);
```

Online demo: http://ideone.com/wmbple

Comment: Dammit I spent 5 minutes typing this out on crappy iPad softkeys just to have some slacker with a real keyboard beat me to the punch.

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes: "just to have some slacker with a real keyboard beat me to the punch" --- "slacker"? Is it a joke?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes For someone typing answers on an iPad, it's debatable who's the slacker =p

Comment: @Jack have you ever tried? All the curlies and everything are hidden behind like 5 keypresses each, and you have to deal with Apple's idea of capitalization :P

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/array_walk):

```
$result = $array1;
array_walk($result, function(&$value, $key) use (&$array2) {
    $value .= ' ' . $array2[$key];
});
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1hXJYq)

This modifies `$result` (copied from `$array1`) in-place with values looked from `$array2` based on the array keys.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to write a **function** for it and keep it in your toolkit:

```
function merge_array() {
    $merged = array();
    $arrays = func_get_args();

    if ($arrays) {
        foreach ($arrays as $array) {
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                if (isset($merged[$key])) {
                    $merged[$key] .= ' ' . $value;
                }
                else {
                    $merged[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $merged;
}
```

Now pass `$array1` and `$array2` to it:

```
$result = merge_array($array1, $array2);
```

And you will get this result:

```
// Array
// (
//     [2013-05-01] => test 1
//     [2013-05-02] => testing done
//     [2013-05-03] => working code
//     [2013-05-04] => future test
//     [2013-05-05] => release
// )
```

**Note that this function accept more than two arrays if you want**.

- `[!]` Check it online at [ideone](http://ideone.com/M6CERC).

Answer (score 0):

array_walk() would be the easiest way to do it.